# eventlog shows invalid column name although I don't have that in my model

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have the following database model class called positions:

```
public class Positions
{
    public string? Id { get; set; }

    public string? ArticlePLU { get; set; }

    public string? ArticleName { get; set; }
    public string? ArticleGroupPlu { get; set; }
    public string? ArticleGroupName { get; set; }
    public string? MenuId { get; set; }
    public string? MenuName { get; set; }
    public string? MenuLineId { get; set; }
    public string? MenuLineName { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; } 

    public List<Vat>? Vat { get; set; }

    public List<AdditionalCost>? AdditionalCost { get; set; }

    public List<Components>? Components { get; set; }

    public Comment Comment { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Orders")]
    public string? OrdersId { get; set; }

}
```

I also have the following class called Comment:

```
    public class Comment
{
    public string? Id { get; set;}

    public string? Type { get; set;}

    public string? Value { get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("Components")]
    public string? ComponentsId;

    [ForeignKey("Positions")]
    public string? PositionsId;

}
```

The class comment is a child of positions but it can also be a child of components, which itself is a child of positions, but I don't think thats relevant to the problem right now.

The eventlog of IIS shows that whenever I try to send data with Postman it cannot recognize a column called **"CommentId"** which does not exist in any classes and isnt referenced anywhere. My guess is that EntityFramework, which im using, is doing something in the background because I have not configured everything correctly. The **'Comment'** data is supposed to be in another table. When the data is received, the **Comment** should get an own unique Id through my controller class and EF handles the foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `Comment` is the non nullable Child of the Position, Entity Framework automatically add Foreign Key`CommentId`
column to the table Positions. In order to solve this, you can make the `Comment` to be Nullable by adding `?` in the Comment Property in Position model

```
public Comment? Comment { get; set; }
```

This will remove EF Core from automatically add new column `CommandId` to table `Positions`

Edit :
Configure using Fluent Api the relationship between Comment and Position..

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Position>()
    .HasOne(p => p.Comment)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Comment>(p => p.PositionsId);
```

Just put this inside your DbContext class. Learn more here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Comment: unfortunately that still didn't work

Comment: Maybe you can configure using Fluent Api the relationship between Comment and Position.. ```modelBuilder.Entity<Position>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Comment)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<Comment>(p => p.PositionsId);``` Just put this inside your DbContext class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key